# R scale by variable and recombine to dataframe

Tags: r

I'm attempting to standardize the data frame (several variables, 2 in example) by variable and recombine the data frame:

```
V1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1,2)
V2<-c(.2,.4,.3,.5,.1,.3,.6,1,0,.5)
Size1<-c("S","S","M","L","M","S","M","L","S","M")
df<-data.frame(V1,V2,Size1)
Size1<-factor(Size1)

AllStand<-data.frame(sapply(df[,1:2],scale),Size1=df$Size1)
```

I need to standardize by Size1.

I tried the split-apply-combine approach

split

```
splitby<-split(df[,1:2],Size1)
```

apply

```
app<-sapply(splitby,scale)
```

And here is a problem where I try to recombine it. The output is list and I need dataframe in the same format as original. I tried tapply/by/with which produce the similar lists in on step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use one of the aggregate by group approach.

Using `dplyr`, we group by 'Size1' and specify the function inside the `funs` in `mutate_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Size1) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(scale))
#           V1         V2 Size1
#1  -0.6301260 -0.1463850     S
#2  -0.2100420  1.0246951     S
#3   0.0000000 -0.3382407     M
#4   0.7071068 -0.7071068     L
#5   1.4142136 -1.2402159     M
#6   1.4702941  0.4391550     S
#7  -0.7071068  1.0147221     M
#8  -0.7071068  0.7071068     L
#9  -0.6301260 -1.3174651     S
#10 -0.7071068  0.5637345     M
```

Or we can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Size1', we loop over the columns (`lapply(.SD`) and `scale`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(scale(x))) , by = Size1]
#      Size1         V1         V2
# 1:     S -0.6301260 -0.1463850
# 2:     S -0.2100420  1.0246951
# 3:     S  1.4702941  0.4391550
# 4:     S -0.6301260 -1.3174651
# 5:     M  0.0000000 -0.3382407
# 6:     M  1.4142136 -1.2402159
# 7:     M -0.7071068  1.0147221
# 8:     M -0.7071068  0.5637345
# 9:     L  0.7071068 -0.7071068
#10:     L -0.7071068  0.7071068
```

Or  we `split` the `data.frame` into a `list`, `scale` the columns by looping with `lapply`, `unsplit` using the same variable 'Size1' and assign the output to replace the first two columns with the `scale`d output.

```
df[,1:2] <- unsplit(lapply(split(df[,1:2], Size1), 
                   function(x) as.data.frame(scale(x))), Size1)
df
#           V1         V2 Size1
#1  -0.6301260 -0.1463850     S
#2  -0.2100420  1.0246951     S
#3   0.0000000 -0.3382407     M
#4   0.7071068 -0.7071068     L
#5   1.4142136 -1.2402159     M
#6   1.4702941  0.4391550     S
#7  -0.7071068  1.0147221     M
#8  -0.7071068  0.7071068     L
#9  -0.6301260 -1.3174651     S
#10 -0.7071068  0.5637345     M
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun . dplyr option is the most elegant. Third option is the one I was looking for

Comment: @KonstantinMingoulin  Thank you for the feedback.